# Combinatorial Proof that $\binom{n\vphantom{d}}{c}\binom{n-d}{b-c}=\binom{n\vphantom{d}}{d}\binom{d}{c}$

Tags: combinations

So I have that $\binom{n}{  c}\times \binom{n-d}{b-c} = \binom{n }{ d}\times  \binom{d}{c}$.

I am trying to prove it by using number of players to prove this. What should be the best way to prove this? I can't seem to figure out what should go in n-d b-c.

Comment: Please check for typos. There is something obviously wrong with the current version, with a $b$ on one side but not the other, ditto with $N$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I think some are unknowns, but it is not clear which ones. The $N$ is most likely $n$, so I changed it. I hope that was not too presumptuous.

Comment: There is an identity
$$
\binom{n}{d}\binom{d}{c}=\binom{n}{c}\binom{n-c}{d-c}
$$
that can be proven by expanding things out into factorials. However, I don't see how to make a useful substitution to get that into your form.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your are looking for, but it is hard to tell from your question.

How many ways are there from a group of $n$ people to make a committee of $d$ people with a board of $c$ people?

Pick the $d$ people for the committee, then from the committee, choose the $c$ board members:
$$
\binom{n}{d}\binom{d}{c}
$$
Pick the $c$ people for the board, then from the remaining $n-c$ people, choose the remaining $d-c$ committee members:
$$
\binom{n}{c}\binom{n-c}{d-c}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\binom{n}{d}\binom{d}{c}=\binom{n}{c}\binom{n-c}{d-c}
$$